# How can you tell if a settlement will have "noble troops" for hire in Bannerlord?

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

By "noble troops" I mean troops like the "Khuzait's Noble Son" which can be upgraded up to tier 6, as opposed to the normal ones that can be upgraded up to tier 5. I can tell that it's related to a settlement's prosperity but there has to be other factors because I've seen villages with 280 hearths offer those troops while others with 300+ hearths offered normal ones.

I've also literally never seen any of those troops for hire in a town, even the ones with 5000+ prosperity. Perhaps only villages can have them?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but possibly useful for you:  You can also acquire Khan's Guard by upgrading from captured Steppe Bandits (via Marauder > Raider > Kheshig) if you have the Veteran's Respect perk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after looking around a bit I have found the answer:

**Noble troops can be hired from villages bound to a castle and not a town**

So nothing to do with prosperity after all. I have checked a few castle-bound villages and I did notice that they all had 2 notables offering noble troops while the third one offered normal troops. This also explains why I've never seen (and will never see, unless it's changed in the future) noble troops as possible recruits from a town.

One neat effect of this is that it increases the value of castles (which are often a net negative in terms of money), since you automatically increase relation with notables when your settlements have high security and thus this means you could get up to 12 noble troops per village without having to spend a lot of time doing small quests for the villages' notables.